# Create pandas MultiIndex from Cartesian Product but "Unfold" Several Levels in the Same way

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to create a MultiIndex in pandas from a Cartesian product, with the catch that one of the levels is "special" and will be associated with an arbitrary number of additional levels that I would like to "unfold" in the same way as the special level. The end result is much easier to demonstrate than describe.

The code below shows a case where I want to create a MultiIndex based on the Cartesian product of `id` and `loc` but have `color` and `shape` unfolded in the same way as 'id'. Two different methods for doing this are shown in the example. For this contrived case these are adequate solutions, but for my real use case where the DataFrame will have > 10 million rows neither of these approaches satisfies my performance requirements. What is the best approach for creating such a MultiIndex?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

id = np.asarray([1,2,3,4,5])
color= np.asarray(['red','blue','green','orange','purple'])
shape = np.asarray(['square','circle','triangle','rectangle','oval'])
loc = np.asarray(['CA','OR'])

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([id,loc], names=['ID','LOC'])
data = np.ravel(np.random.rand(5,2))

# Approach 1
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx)
df1['color'] = color[idx.labels[0]]
df1['shape'] = shape[idx.labels[0]]
df1.set_index(['color','shape'],append=True,inplace=True)
print(df1)

# Approach 2 
idx2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([id[idx.labels[0]],loc[idx.labels[1]],color[idx.labels[0]],shape[idx.labels[0]]],names=['ID','LOC','color','shape'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx2)
print(df2)
```

Answer (score 1):

### `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples` v1

```
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [(id[i], l, color[i], shape[i])
     for i in range(len(id)) for l in loc],
    names=['ID', 'LOC', 'color', 'shape']
)

df3 = pd.DataFrame(data, midx)

df3

                                0
ID LOC color  shape              
1  CA  red    square     0.583714
   OR  red    square     0.038577
2  CA  blue   circle     0.879020
   OR  blue   circle     0.542611
3  CA  green  triangle   0.185523
   OR  green  triangle   0.289909
4  CA  orange rectangle  0.788596
   OR  orange rectangle  0.915843
5  CA  purple oval       0.701603
   OR  purple oval       0.726648
```

---

### `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples` v2

```
i, j = np.indices((len(id), len(loc)))
a = np.column_stack([
    np.column_stack([id, color, shape])[i.ravel()],
    loc[j.ravel()]
])[:, [0, -1, 1, 2]]

midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(a.tolist(), names=['ID', 'LOC', 'color', 'shape'])

df4 = pd.DataFrame(data, midx)

df4

                                0
ID LOC color  shape              
1  CA  red    square     0.583714
   OR  red    square     0.038577
2  CA  blue   circle     0.879020
   OR  blue   circle     0.542611
3  CA  green  triangle   0.185523
   OR  green  triangle   0.289909
4  CA  orange rectangle  0.788596
   OR  orange rectangle  0.915843
5  CA  purple oval       0.701603
   OR  purple oval       0.726648
```